# Strapi responding 401 unauthorized suddenly despite providing Bearer token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, strapi

Everything was working fine 24hrs ago, suddenly 401 error rose
following are the details of request being made by react-app (client)

**custom fetching hook useFetch.js**

```
const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);

        const res = await makeRequest.get(url, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "bearer " + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN,
          },
        });

        setData(res.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(true);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [url]);

  return { data, loading, error };
};
```

**makeRequest.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const makeRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: "bearer " + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN,
  },
});
```

Also tried regenerating token as I thought it would had expired but no positive results

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Go to the admin panel -> Settings -> roles and check if that the role which you're currently signing in to is allowed to do that particular transaction or not. in your use case, if you're making the simple get request, confirm that the `find` and `findOne` options are ticked for the particular collection.

Comment: Role from which i am operating is Super Admin and all the permissions are given. Also find and findOne are applied from Api Token section

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue, in my case it was wrong placement of .env file. It should be under "client/" (I've had under "client/src" and it was root cause").

Try to console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN) and process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL in order to make sure if its the same as in Strapi admin.

Regarding your code - there is no need to provide headers twice in makeRequest function:

```
const res = await makeRequest.get(url)
```

is enough as you are providing authorization token already in makeRequest.js file.